Nextjs favicon.ico not showing
I use Nextjs 14.2.5 app directory in this project.\
The favicon.ico is correctly put in app file.
When I check the elements, I can see the favicon link as below picture.
But somehow it's just not showing.

I know the other way to set favicon is to adjust the metadata.
I tried it but still it doesn't work.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

If the favicon is correctly placed according to the docs, it is most likely due to your browser cache. Try opening your site in an incognito tab or clear your browser cache.
